# How to unit test azure functions blob storage trigger option?

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-blob-storage

I have an azure function which is triggered when a zip file is uploaded to an azure blob storage container. I unzip the file in memory and process the contents and add/update the result into a database. While for the db part I can use the in memory db option. Somehow am not too sure how to simulate the blob trigger for  unit testing this azure function.

All the official samples and some blogs mostly talk about Http triggers(mocking httprequest) and queue triggers (using IAsynCollection).

```
[FunctionName("AzureBlobTrigger")]
        public void Run([BlobTrigger("logprocessing/{name}", Connection = "AzureWebJobsStorage")]Stream blobStream, string name, ILogger log)
        {
            log.LogInformation($"C# Blob trigger function Processed blob\n Name:{name} \n Size: {blobStream.Length} Bytes");
            //processing logic
        }
```

Comment: What does your blob trigger look like?

Comment: can you solve you issue by the post below?

Comment: @IvanYang I had seen this github code earlier. It did not help all that much. also the approach changed in my case and I did not get to work on this yet.

Answer (score 3):

There is a project about Unit test/ Integration test about azure function including `blob trigger` in [github](https://github.com/jeffhollan/functions-test-helper), please take a try at your side. Note that the unit test code is in `FunctionApp.Tests` folder.

Some code snippet about blob trigger from github:

**unit test code of BlobFunction.cs**

```
namespace FunctionApp.Tests
{
    public class BlobFunction : FunctionTest
    {
        [Fact]
        public async Task BlobFunction_ValidStreamAndName()
        {
            Stream s = new MemoryStream();
            using(StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(s))
            {
                await sw.WriteLineAsync("This is a test");
                BlobTrigger.Run(s, "testBlob", log);
            }
        }
    }
}
```